# Dupicate LFO Signal and Invert, keeping MAXs and MINs

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, signal-processing, inverting-amplifier, small-signal

Im working on a Dual LFO with "Depth" and Rate controls. I already got the "root" LFO signal working and if I do this, I can generate the LFO swinging from 0v to 9v... and with Less Depth from, say, 8v to 9v:
[image]
[image]

**Now I need the same signal but with the direction inverted** (when the first one goes up, the second one goes down) **BUT having the same Maxs and Mins.**

If I do this (img below), with Depth at minimum I get, say, 8v to 9v in the first one, but 0v to 1v in the second one...
[image]
[image]

and I want the same 8v to 9v, but with the orientation being the inverse, like this:
[image]

Things I already know how to do:

- Invert a signal
- Add DC Offset to signal (but the offset always changes depending on the Depth)
- Remove DC Offset to signal
- Substract two signals
- Sum two signals

I need to figure this out!! There has to be a simple way!

**UPDATE::**

I came up with this math: 9v - 2 * Signal(without offset, centered on 0)

Based on that I made this simplification for testing the concept where I generate the two signals:
LFO1 goes from 7 to 9
AUX_SIM goes from -1 to 1 (just LFO1 without the offset)

And it works:
[image]

SO, then I generate the AUX_SIM from LFO1 removing the offset and is ok:
[image]

BUT when I put it all together, The LFO1 without the offset is not centered on Cero and everything shifts, because life is HARD :D

[image]

I thought I was close this time... Any ideas??

Comment: This would be easier if you have a dual-gang potentiometer. Do you?

Comment: Yes, I though about that. But I want to make it with simpler components and now I want to solve the challenge! :D

Comment: I'm not actually sure it's possible without significant complexity, but I don't have time right now to give it much thought.

Comment: @Hearth I edited the original question with new insight!

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you want but, I would run it through a simulator first if I were you: -

[image]

You should also make sure that you have power rails on your op-amp that are in excess of 9 volts and preferably 12 volts (for most bog-standard op-amps). I mention this because you didn't say what power rails the op-amp receives.

Comment: Hi Andy. I tried that but didn't work. It doesn't even invert the signal. Im connecting the opamp to 9v and ground. That's why I put VREF on the Positive pin of it, with 4.5v

Comment: What op-amp did you use? Wrong op-amp and it won't work. Even with the best op-amp you might need a positive supply slightly higher than 9 volts such as 9.1 volts.

Comment: I'm using UniversalOpamp2 in Eagle (the one in the image was the generic one just for simplicity). I edited the original post with new insights and the exact schematic and plot Im using. I always use that opamp without problems.

Comment: Those additions don't help and contradict your original schematic. You should repeat the circuit using the potentiometer (as originally disclosed) but with a higher positive rail for the op-amp like 12 volts @ElectronOne

Comment: Im going to power the device with 9v battery, and the LFO that I already designed (it also has a Shape control) swings from 0 to 9v  :/

Comment: I tested it with the potentiometer and has the same behaviour that with the Signal Generator. I posted it with the generator to isolate the issue with that new approach

Comment: It won't work when you come to build it unless you test using a proper op-amp that has real-life limitations. I've done all I can here to point you in the correct direction.